# How to implement "free-form" relation in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm using EF 6 to work with a somewhat shoddily constructed database. I'm using a code-first model.

A lot of the logical relations there aren't implemented correctly using keys, but use various other strategies (Such as character-separated ids or strings, for example) that were previously manipulated using complex SQL queries.

(Changing the schema is not an option)

I really want to capture those relations as properties. It's possible to do this by using explicit queries instead of defining actual relations using the fluent/attribute syntax.

I'm planning to do this by having `IQueryable<T>` properties that perform a query. For example:

```
partial class Product {
    public IQueryable<tblCategory> SubCategories {
        get {
            //SubCategoriesID is a string like "1234, 12351, 12" containing a list of IDs.
            var ids = SubCategoriesID.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x.Trim()));
            return from category in this.GetContext().tblCategories
                where ids.Contains(category.CategoryID)
                select category;
        }
    }
}
```

(The `GetContext()` method is an extension method that somehow acquires an appropriate `DbContext`)

However, is there a better way to do this that I'm not familiar with?

Furthermore, if I do do this, what's the best way of getting the `DbContext` for the operation? It could be:

1. Just create a new one. I'm a bit leery of doing this, since I don't know much about how they work.
2. Use some tricks to get the context that was used to create this specific instance.
3. Do something else?

Answer (score 1):

First, I would recommend not returning an IQueryable, as that retains a relationship to the original DbContext. Instead, I'd `ToList` the results of the query and return that as an `IEnumerable<tblCategory>`

Try not to keep `DbContext` instances hanging around; there's a lot of state management baked into them, and since they are not thread-safe you don't want to have multiple threads hitting the same instance. The pattern I personally tend to follow on data access methods is to use a new `DbContext` in a using block:

```
using (var ctx = new YourDbContextTypeHere()) {
  return (from category in ctx.tblCategories
            where ids.Contains(category.CategoryID)
            select category).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Beware that .Contains() on a list of ids is very slow in EF, i.e. try to avoid it. I'd use subqueries, such as

```
var subcategories = context.SubCategories.Where(...);
var categories = context.Categories.Where(x => subCategories.Select(x => x.Id).Contains(category.CategoryId);
```

In this setup, you can avoid loading all the ids onto the server, and the query will be fast.

Comment: I don't see how this code has anything to do with the problem or with my circumstances. Since the column contains a list of Ids, I have to deal with it somehow. I could use `String.Contains` but I suspect that would be even slower. Also, could you source your statement that `Contains` is very slow? I'd like to know why. I'd think it would just be mapped to an `IN` kind of statement.

Comment: The problem is that EF cannot pre-compile anything with lists of arguments. You are right that the SQL will be generated with IN, but the compilation to parse the expression tree for EF can be very substantial (longer than the execution of the SQL query itself). Whenever EF cannot precompile, it is dreadfully slow...